# jQuery siblings and $(this) blur and focus

Tags: jquery, focus, this, blur, siblings

I have a form with labels and input fields. When clicking into a field I want to style the field with CSS and display some information about the input requirements in a div under the label.

The focus() and blur() events add the classes for styling the field just fine but trying to show/ hide the info divs triggers the methods on ALL fields using $(this).siblings()

```
$(".input-field").focus(function() { 
    $(this).addClass("input-field-focus");
    $(this).siblings(".label-info").show();
    return false; 
});
$(".input-field").blur(function() { 
    $(this).removeClass("input-field-focus");
    $(this).siblings(".label-info").hide();
    return false; 
});


<label for="login">
    User name:<br />
    <div class="label-info">minimum 6 chararcters: letters, numbers and symbols - _ . @</div>
    <input type="text" name="login" class="input-field" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['login'])) ? $_POST['login'] : ""; ?>">
</label>
```

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsbin.com/obuzi3

Comment: Hi Felix, it doesn't work with 2 fields, shows / hides both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now I see the problem. Your HTML markup is wrong. You cannot have a `div` element inside `label`, use `span` instead:

```
<label for="login">User name:
    <br />
    <span class="label-info">minimum 6 chararcters: letters, numbers and symbols - _ . @</span>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="login" class="input-field" value="">
</label>
```

or wrap the whole block in an own `div`:

```
<div>
    <label for="login">User name:</label>
    <div class="label-info">minimum 6 chararcters: letters, numbers and symbols - _ . @</siv>
    <input type="text" name="login" class="input-field" value="">
</div>
```

---

Otherwise the browser will correct the markup producing this:

```
<label for="login">
    User name:<br />
</label> 
<div class="label-info">minimum 6 chararcters: letters, numbers and symbols - _ . @</div>
<input type="text" name="login" class="input-field" value="">
```

So every `label-info` and input element will be on the same level and therefore siblings to each other.

Comment: Felix, I have an example with 2 fields and your correction here: http://jsfiddle.net/7wxZy/ But still the same problem??

Comment: @FFish: No, you did it wrong. Either change the `div` to `span` but still have the `label` tag around it **or** keep the `div` and put another `div` around the the `label`, `div` and `input`. You are missing this "wrapping" `div` in your example. It should be more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7wxZy/6/

Comment: Sorry reading a little better, you are right.. Thanks Felix!!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

Based on your updated code, you should be using `.prev()` instead of `.siblings()`.

```
$(".input-field").focus(function() {
    $(this).addClass("input-field-focus");
    $(this).prev(".label-info").show();
    return false;
});
$(".input-field").blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("input-field-focus");
    $(this).prev(".label-info").hide();
    return false;
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/prev/
- http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

---

**Original answer:**

Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/D9qnk/

My guess is that your are initially hiding the `.label-info` using `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display:none;`

If that's the case, switch your css to use `display:none` instead.

```
.label-info {
    display: none;
}​
```

Or if you want to use the `visibility` property, then change its value using `.css()`:

```
$(this).siblings(".label-info").css('visibility','visible');

...

$(this).siblings(".label-info").css('visibility','hidden');
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for showing jsfiddle, awsome indeed. I just updated the code to show the problem.. with 2 fields it shows both divs.

Comment: @FFish - I updated your jsFiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/7wxZy/4/  You should use `.prev()` instead of `.siblings()`, since `.siblings()` will match *all* siblings, whereas `.prev()` will only look at the previous sibling. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Cheers Patrick, this is even better than Felix solution as I have more CSS control over the DIV's. Here is my final example: http://jsfiddle.net/7wxZy/29/

Comment: @FFish: You should still try to generate valid HTML.

Comment: @FFish - Looks good, but @Felix is right. You shouldn't have `block` elements inside of `inline` elements.